# Graphics Acceleration Enable: No “Hardware Section” in AVD

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device, hardware-acceleration

I want to have graphics acceleration enabled for my AVD and instructions say If you want to have graphics acceleration enabled by default for this AVD, in the Hardware section, click New, select GPU emulation and set the value to Yes. The problem is I do not have a hardware section that I can see. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

While creating a new AVD select "Use Host GPU" option given at the bottom. The new AVD layout does not show hardware section at the bottom as it used to show previously.

Answer (score 0):

I got this from [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration), according to it it should run an app with OpenGl ES 2.0 but didn't worked for me.
If you are running from ecplipse, the only way to activate GPU emulation is to activate Host GPU while creating the virtual device, then, in the Run/Run configurations of your android proyect select the Target tab, select the AVD that you created (it should be on a list in that window), next, down there, in the Additional Emulator Command Line Options field, enter "-gpu on" (no quotes), save and run the application from there, it should open the AVD and run the App.